# openpyxl.load_workbook function won't return class - "No such file or directory" error despite it being in right directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to return the class of my Excel document, but it won't. The error that I get is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wellbeing.xlsx'` despite the fact that I have changed to the right directory. Here is my code.

```
import openpyxl
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wellbeing.xlsx')
type(wb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Make sure the file is present at this location. It could be possible that it is renamed.

Second, check whether Python has successfully changed the directory. You can do this using the `os.getcwd()` method. I am not sure why you used `type(wb)`. Maybe you wanted to check the `type` of the variable `wb`. Your code section is not edited properly.

Here's what you can do:

```
import os
import openpyxl

os.chdir('C:\Users\Simon\Desktop')
os.getcwd()         # to check the current working directory

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wellbeing.xlsx')
wb.sheetnames       # to get all sheet names in the Excel spreadsheet
type(wb)            # openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook
```

The best way to get the correct path of a file(and be sure that it's present):

1) Go to the file and press Shift+right-click on the file and select *Copy as path*:

[image: Copy file path]

2) Next, paste the copied path in `os.chdir()` in the code below, excluding the filename 'wellbeing.xlsx'.

3) Run the following code to check if Python can open and read the contents in the file. The `readlines()` function reads the contents line-by-line. We will `print` this to see if we can get the contents displayed.

```
import os
import openpyxl

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop')
with open("wellbeing.xlsx" ,'r') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting and thanks for the answer. I have doubled checked the working directory and it still gives me the same error. I will paste it below.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceltryer.py", line 7, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wellbeing.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 174, in load_workbook
    archive = _validate_archive(filename)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 121, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wellbeing.xlsx'

Comment: import os
    import openpyxl

    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\')
    show = os.getcwd()    # to check the current working directory

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wellbeing.xlsx')
    wb.sheetnames       # to get all sheet names in the Excel 
    spreadsheet
    type(wb)

Comment: To edit the code section, just select the code and press Ctrl + K. Meanwhile, I am updating my answer with some useful information.